# autocompletar input con un valor anterior

Tags: php, javascript, html5, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

tengo como un pequeño formulario, uno de los campos es n° de factura, lo que necesito es que al momento de generar otra fila, el campo de n° de factura se autocomplete con el valor de la primera vez que los escribi, sin necesidad de volverlo a escribir

```
 <body> 
  <form action="POST"> 
   <div id="container">
   N° Referencia:<input type="TEXT" name="nfactura" id="factura">
   Descripcion <input type="TEXT" name="descripcion" id="descripcion"> 
   Modelo:<input type="TEXT" name="modelo" id="modelo"> 
   Serial:<input type="TEXT" name="serial" id="serial"> 
    <a href="#" id="add"> Add More</a> 
   </div> 
   <p></p> 
   <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit"> 
  </form> 
 
</body>
```

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    //Variables
     var html = 
       '<p /><div>N° Factura:<input type="TEXT" name="nfactura" id="childnfactura">Descripcion: <input type="TEXT" name="descripcion"    id="childdescripcion"   /> Modelo: <input type="TEXT" name="modelo"  id="childmodelo"  /> Serial: <input type="TEXT" name="serial"    id="childserial" /> <a href="#" id="remove">X</a></div>';
     var maxrows = 5;
     var x = 1;
    //agregar filas al form
    $("#add").click(function(e){
        $("#container").append(html);
    });
    //remover filas del form
    $("#container").on('click','#remove',function(e){
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez agregando tu html a una función para que puedas mandar como parámetro la factura pueda servirte, mira el código como lo modifique seguro te sirve.

**EDIT:**
Explicacion:
Uso un ternario `(fact ?: '')` para evaluar en caso de que fact exista, te retornara al input fact dentro de value, en caso contrario no hace nada dentro del value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  //Variables
  function inputs(fact) {
    return '<p /><div>N° Factura:<input type="TEXT" name="nfactura" id="childnfactura" value=' + (fact ? fact : '') + '>Descripcion: <input type="TEXT" name="descripcion"    id="childdescripcion"   /> Modelo: <input type="TEXT" name="modelo"  id="childmodelo"  /> Serial: <input type="TEXT" name="serial"    id="childserial" /> <a href="#" id="remove">X</a></div>';
  }

  var maxrows = 5;
  var x = 1;
  //agregar filas al form
  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    //let factura = $('#childnfactura').val();
    let factura = $('#factura').val();
    $("#container").append(inputs(factura));
  });
  //remover filas del form
  $("#container").on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form action="POST">
    <div id="container">
      N° Referencia:<input type="TEXT" name="nfactura" id="factura"> Descripcion <input type="TEXT" name="descripcion" id="descripcion"> Modelo:
      <input type="TEXT" name="modelo" id="modelo"> Serial:
      <input type="TEXT" name="serial" id="serial">
      <a href="#" id="add"> Add More</a>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit">
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Oye hermano esta perfecto, lo unico es que se autocompleta pero a partir de la segunda vez que le doy "add more" o sea escribo el numero de factura en la primera, le doy a "add more" me aparece la nueva fila pero no autocompleto, pero cuando le doy click en "addmore" de nuevo ahi si me autocompleta el input

Comment: Ah, pensé que referencia era distinto, pero en ese caso solo cambia esta parte `let factura = $('#childnfactura').val();`, por este `factura` porque tienen distintos id, pense que era diferente, mira lo edite.

Comment: no no disculpa es qie no habia modificado ahi, me di cuenta cuando me diste la respuesta, disculpa otra vez xD

Comment: dale ntp jaja, si la respuesta te sirvió márcala como respondida, para que otros también puedan guiarse en un futuro

Comment: Ahora si perfecto, muchisimas gracias, te mereces una cerveza como dicen aqui en Venezuela "vestida de novia", o sea bien friita hhahahahahahhahaha

Comment: jajajaja gracias, suerte en todo estamos para apoyarnos :D